# Printing shortest path in adjacency matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix

I've made a Network (directed weighted graph) that contains an adjacency matrix with vertices and weighted edges.

I've got a Path class set up, and a Queue of potential paths, and a Deque of possible solutions. If a node has already been visited, it is marked as visited, otherwise it is added to the potential paths, and its adjacent nodes are checked. Then, the best path is calculated, based on weight.

I'm having problems with returning a String of the shortest path. I'm trying to produce a string of the vertices in the shortest path, from origin to destination. However, when I test and run getShortestPath, I get memory locations rather than String values.

Here's the code for the shortest path:

```
// get shortest path from a starting vertex to ending vertex

  public String getShortestPath(String origin, String destination)
  {
    origin = origin.toUpperCase();
    destination = destination.toUpperCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
      return findShortestPath(origin, destination).toString();
    }
    return "";
  }

  public List<Edge> adjacentEdges(String origin)
  {
    List<Edge> result = new LinkedList<Edge>();

    for (Edge e : edges)
    {
      if (e.origin.name.compareTo(origin) == 0)
        result.add(new Edge(e.origin, e.destination, e.weight));
    }
    return result;
  }

  public Path findShortestPath(String origin, String destination)
  {
    if (origin.compareTo(destination) == 0)
    {
      return null;
    }

    Queue<Path> potentialPaths = new LinkedList<Path>();

    for (Edge e : adjacentEdges(origin))
    {
      Path current = new Path();
      current.edges.add(new Edge(e.origin, e.destination, e.weight));
      potentialPaths.add(current);
      System.out.println(potentialPaths);
    }

    Deque<Path> solutions = new LinkedList<Path>();

    while (!potentialPaths.isEmpty())
    {
      Path current = potentialPaths.remove(); // dequeue
      String[] nodes = current.toString().split("-");
      Edge last = current.edges.getLast();

      if (last.destination.name.compareTo(destination) == 0) // found valid path
      {
        solutions.add(current);
        continue;
      }
      // if not at the destination
      List<Edge> adjacencies = adjacentEdges(last.destination.name);

      for (Edge adj : adjacencies)
      {
        boolean visited = false;

        for (Edge pe : current.edges)
        {
          if (adj.destination.name.compareTo(pe.origin.name) == 0) // already been to this node in the path
          {
            visited = true;
          }
        }

        // if not already visited, add edge to path and enqueue it to potential paths
        if (!visited)
        {
          Path candidate = new Path();

          for (Edge pe : current.edges)
          {
            candidate.edges.add(new Edge(pe.origin, pe.destination, pe.weight));
          }

          candidate.edges.add(new Edge(adj.origin, adj.destination, adj.weight));

          potentialPaths.add(candidate);
        }
      }
    }
    // done going through all potential paths
    // loop through solutions for best weight

    if (solutions.isEmpty())
      return null;

    Path best = solutions.remove();
    double weight = calcWeight(best);

    while (!(solutions.isEmpty()))
    {
      Path current = solutions.remove();
      double currentWeight = calcWeight(current);

      if (currentWeight < weight)
      {
        best = current;
        weight = currentWeight;
      }
    }

    return best;
  }

  public double calcWeight(Path path)
  {
    double weight = 0.0;

    for (Edge e : path.edges)
    {
      weight += e.weight;
    }

    return weight;
  }

  public class Path
  {
    public Deque<Edge> edges;

    public Path()
    {
      edges = new LinkedList<Edge>();
    }
  }
```

And the rest of my Network class code, if needed:

```
public class Network
{
  // instance variables

  public List<Vertex> vertices;
  public List<Edge> edges;

  // constructor

  public Network()
  {
    vertices = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
    edges = new LinkedList<Edge>();
  }

  // adjacency matrix

  public class AdjacencyMatrix
  {
    String vertexNames[];
    double matrix[][];

    public AdjacencyMatrix()
    {
      final int size = vertices.size();
      vertexNames = new String[size];
      matrix = new double[size][size];

      int i = 0;
      for (Vertex v : vertices)
      {
        vertexNames[i++] = v.name;
      }


    for (Edge e : edges)
    {
      int row = getIndex(e.origin.name);
      int column = getIndex(e.destination.name);
      matrix[row][column] = e.weight;
    }
  }

   private int getIndex(String name)
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < vertexNames.length; i++)
      {
       if (vertexNames[i].compareTo(name) == 0)
         return i;
       }
     return -1;
     }
  }

  // getAdjacencyMatrix

  public AdjacencyMatrix getAdjacencyMatrix()
  {
    return new AdjacencyMatrix();
  }

 // add vertices 

  public boolean addVertex(String name)
  {
    for (Vertex v : vertices)
    {
      if (v.name.compareTo(name) == 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

      Vertex v = new Vertex(name);
      v.name = name.toUpperCase();
      vertices.add(v);
      return true;
  }

  // add edges

  public boolean addEdge(String origin, String destination, double weight)
  {
    origin = origin.toUpperCase();
    destination = destination.toUpperCase();

    Vertex originVertex = null;

    for (Vertex v : vertices)
    {
      if (v.name.compareTo(origin) == 0)
      {
        originVertex = v;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (originVertex == null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    Vertex destinationVertex = null;

    for (Vertex v : vertices)
    {
      if (v.name.compareTo(destination) == 0)
      {
        destinationVertex = v;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (destinationVertex == null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    for (Edge e : edges)
    {
      if (e.origin == originVertex && e.destination == destinationVertex)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    Edge e = new Edge(originVertex, destinationVertex, weight);
    e.origin = originVertex;
    e.destination = destinationVertex;
    e.weight = weight;
    edges.add(e);

    return true;
  }

  // support classes

  public class Vertex<T extends Comparable>
  {
    public String name;

    public List<Edge> edges;

    public Vertex(String name)
    {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  public class Edge
  {
    public Vertex origin, destination;
    public double weight;

    public Vertex getSource()
    {
      return origin;
    }

    public Vertex getDestination()
    {
      return destination;
    }

    public int getWeight()
    {
      return (int)weight;
    }

    public Edge(Vertex origin, Vertex destination, double weight)
    {
      this.origin = origin;
      this.destination = destination;
      this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Edge(String origin, String destination, double weight)
    {
      this.origin = new Vertex(origin);
      this.destination = new Vertex(destination);
      this.weight = weight;
    }
  }

  public List<Vertex> getVertices()
  {
    return vertices;
  }

  public List<Edge> getEdges()
  {
    return edges;
  }
```

Comment: It sure looks like the result that comes back is an object of the class Path, and since you have not overRidden its toString method, it is giving you the address of the path.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:[mcve]".  Without mcve one can only guess that `Path.toString()` is not defined.  Also this loop `for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
      return findShortestPath(origin, destination).toString();
    }` is executed only once.